# CS1061 with Html.BeginForm when using a parent / child model in MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have 2 tables in SQL Server, *table1* and *table2*, with the following records. My objective is to **display** and **update** records from both tables in a single view in MVC.

[image]

I have two *child* classes, **table1** and **table2**. I also have one *parent* class, **BothTables**. The BothTables parent class contains child classes table1 and table2.

MODEL

```
namespace www.example.com.Models
{    
    public class table1
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string column1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class table2
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string column1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class BothTables
    {
        public IEnumerable<table1> TableOne{ get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<table2> TableTwo{ get; set; }
    }

    public class example_db : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<table1> table1 { get; set; }
        public DbSet<table2> table2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

CONTROLLER

```
namespace www.example.com.Controllers
{
   public class ContentController : Controller
   {
       private example_db db = new example_db();

       public ActionResult Details(int id)
       {
           using (var db = new example_db())
           {
               var model = new BothTables()
               {
                  TableOne = db.table1.Where(x => x.id.Equals(id)).ToList(),
                  TableTwo = db.table2.Where(x => x.id.Equals(id)).ToList()
               };
               return View(model);
           }
        }
   }
}
```

I can then display records from both table1 and table2 from a single view.

VIEW

```
@model www.example.com.Models.BothTables

@foreach (var item in Model.TableOne)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.column1)
}

@foreach (var item in Model.TableTwo)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.column1)
}
```

This is good. Both **foo** from table1 and **bar** from table2 are displayed in a single view.

[image]

I am struggling now for nearly 2 weeks to figure out how to create an *Html.BeingForm* that will insert records into table2 from the single view. I've read countless articles and watched many YouTube videos, and I just can't seem to find the solution to this one.

I've added this to my controller.

CONTROLLER

```
       [HttpPost]
       [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
       public ActionResult Details(table2 TableTwo)
       {
          if (ModelState.IsValid)
          {
             db.table2.Add(TableTwo);
             db.SaveChanges();
          }
          BothTables BothTables = new BothTables();
          return View(BothTables);
       }
```

I have added the following to the VIEW.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.TableTwo.id)
}
```

When I navigate to www.example.com/Content/Details/1, the following error appears, with line 9 highlighted red:

> CS1061 'IEnumerable table2' does not contain a definition for 'id' and no extension method 'id' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable table2' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Line 7:  @using (Html.BeingForm())
>
> Line 8:  {
>
> Line 9:    **@Html.EditorFor(x => x.TableTwo.id)**
>
> Line 10: }

Comment: 'BothTables' doesn't has 'Id' Property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to insert a record in `table2` you could adjust your view model for this purpose:

```
public class Table2ViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Column1 { get; set; }
}

public class BothTables
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<table1> TableOne { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<table2> TableTwo { get; set; }

    public Table2ViewModel Table2 { get; set; }
}
```

that can be populated in your GET action:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    using (var db = new example_db())
    {
        var model = new BothTables()
        {
            Id = id,
            TableOne = db.table1.Where(x => x.id.Equals(id)).ToList(),
            TableTwo = db.table2.Where(x => x.id.Equals(id)).ToList(),
            Table2 = new Table2ViewModel(),
        };

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

and then in your view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Table2)
    <input type="submit">Insert</input>
}
```

and finally your POST action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Details(BothTables viewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // some required fields were not populated => we need to
        // redisplay the view so that the user can fix the errors
        // Don't forget to populate the 2 fields:
        using (var db = new example_db())
        {
            viewModel.TableOne = db.table1.Where(x => x.id == viewModel.Id).ToList(),
            viewModel.TableTwo = db.table2.Where(x => x.id == viewModel.Id).ToList(),
        }

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    // At this stage we know that the model is valid
    // and we can save it to the database

    var entity = new table2();
    var entity.column1 = viewModel.Table2.Column1;
    db.table2.Add(entity);
    db.SaveChanges();

    // Redirect back to the original GET /Content/Details/1 action
    // (Redirect-After-Post pattern)
    return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = viewModel.Id });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> 'IEnumerable table2' does not contain a definition for 'id' and no
>   extension method 'id' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable
>   table2' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

That's correct. Because `IEnumerable<table2>` is a sequence and therefore does not contain a definition for `id`. What you want is a single item from that sequence. So you should probably change your model declaration in your view and probably create another viewmodel for that purpose and use that instead.